# Can't run any JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm brand new to JavaScript and very new to vsc and I can't execute even the simplest, copy-pasted 1 liner code from a tutorial.

I started with a simple calculator tutorial which provided all the source code. Wouldn't go. Fast forward to now and I'm down to 1 line of JavaScript and at this point I'd do cartwheels if I could just get a console log output.

I searched SO and found a few related answers. Per those answers, I got the extension "Code Runner" which didn't help. From a previous tutorial, I've already downloaded Node.js which appears to be recognized by VSC. It's a run time and debugging option. So that means it's there, I assume?

Here's my big project:

`console.log("Hello, World!");`

If I run the command node hello.js I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\hello\hello.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

If I try with Code Runner I get this error:

```
c:\js\hello.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { alert("Hello, World!");
                                                              ^

ReferenceError: alert is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\js\hello.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

I'm completely lost. I'm not a professional coder. I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand you. But are you planing to use HTML? If that is the case you may want to look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: If you are running in node, `alert` will not exist.

Comment: @Devloop80 I *was* planning on using HTML. It was part of the calculator tutorial. But now I'm just trying to run the minimal possible code just to get my environment properly configured. Maybe the snippet I posted can't run on it's own? I don't know. I tried googling every variation of "minimal possible javascript" and couldn't find anything useful. All I want to do is get VSC to run *ANY* js.

Comment: Node.js only runs a certain part of JavaScript. But first you have to clarify some things: Is your code located in "C:\hello\hello.js" or "C:\js\hello.js"? Do you want to run `console.log("Hello, World!");` or `alert("Hello, World!");`?

Comment: Okey. Then you should start with creating a HTML-page: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp. Next you can add javascript on that HTML-page: https://www.w3schools.com/js

Comment: @AdamPrime, as I said in my answer, for HTML purposes, NodeJS is probably unnecessary unless you want a backend.

Your calculator tutorial probably doesn't use a backend. Could you provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: Ah dang, I pasted the wrong error message. But I got it working now with `console.log("Hello, World!");` I'm honestly not even sure how I fixed it. I disabled Code Runner and it started going. I found something that says Code Runner has a problem with the "default" environment. I don't know what that means and I guess I don't get to use Code Runner. But at least it works now!

Comment: @str NodeJS doesn't "run certain parts of javascript", NodeJS runs JavaScript. Things like `alert`, `setTimeout`, `setInterval` are all part of the WebApi. Yes, NodeJS has some WebApi implementations, but not all of them.

Comment: @Baruch You are (mostly) correct. But Node.js does still not have first-class support for ESM (it is hidden behind a flag) which has been in the ECMAScript specification since 2015. And be it as it may, this information is overkill for a JavaScript beginner ;)

Comment: This looks like a good question - it has some code, it has stack traces, and it has an explanation of what you have tried. I recommend that you do not add pleading material or tales of woe from your prior questions - unfortunately that is like putting a downvote target on your back. [My post here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) opened up some interesting discussion - the theory there is that using confident language, and not minding the odd downvote, will get you a much easier ride here.

Comment: (People may not like the sentiment in your avatar though - there is some leeway on people's profile pages, but if someone might think of it as coarse, vulgar or making light of violence, then you gave them a reason to DV your posts. I tend to recommend more neutral avatars for new members for this reason!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to use NodeJS to run your JavaScript server-side, the correct command would be:
`node hello.js`
This is because your `hello.js` file is not a command in itself. Rather you need `node` (which is a command you get after installing NodeJS) to run it for you.

If, however, you mean to run this in a webpage on the frontend, you'll need an HTML page that you can open in your browser with your JS in a `script` tag.
To learn basic frontend JS, go here: https://w3schools.com/js

To learn basic serverside JS, go here: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/

I could give a better answer if you explained what your end goal is here.

NOTE: Apparently W3Schools may teach some things incorrectly, so you may also look here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript is a much better resource to learn about JavaScript.

Comment: That's a matter of personal opinion. Personally, I think W3Schools is much easier for a beginner to navigate.

I mostly use MDN for reference, rather than for tutorials on beginning JS.

Comment: W3Schools also has a track record of teaching incorrect terminology and other mistakes.

Comment: Hmm...I've never heard that. But I'll add your link to my answer with a note.

Comment: Really appreciate your help @CalebH. (and everyone else)! I got it figured out by disabling Code Runner. Not sure why that helped but it did. I marked your answer as correct because of your valuable resources to help me moving forward. Thanks for giving me my first positive interaction at SO.